# Spring-security oauth2 custom AuthenticationProvider

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have used jwt tokens, oauth2.
I can't receive tokens with my custom provider. I found an admin in DB, all good, but I didn't receive any tokens. I put /oauth/authorize in setAuthenticationSuccessHandler and I see in postman:
the page from setAuthenticationSuccessHandler (I tried to put /oauth/authorize here, but it didn't help)

What should I correct?
p.s. I haven't used the email yet, because it have't worked.
The custom provider class:

```
@Component
public class AdminProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CheckPasswordWhenLogin checkPasswordWhenLogin;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authentication;
        String userName = token.getName();
        String domain = token.getDomain();
        String checkPassword = token.getCredentials().toString();
        String email = userName + "@" + domain;

        Admin admin = adminRepository.findAdminByUsername(userName);

        String password = admin.getPassword();
        //here I check password with encode
        if(!checkPasswordWhenLogin.checkPassword(checkPassword,password)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid username/password");
        }
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = translate();

        return new DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(admin, password, domain, authorities);
    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> translate() {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.equals(authentication);
    }
}
```

The security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AdminProvider adminProvider;

    @Override
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(adminProvider);
    }

    @Bean(name = "pass")
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }



    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(jwtTokenEnhancer());
    }

    @Bean
    protected JwtAccessTokenConverter jwtTokenEnhancer() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("Demo-Key-1");

        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler(TokenStore tokenStore) {
        TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler handler = new TokenStoreUserApprovalHandler();
        handler.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
        handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ApprovalStore approvalStore(TokenStore tokenStore) throws Exception {
        TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
        store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
        return store;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/h2/**").permitAll()

                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/signup/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/errors/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/events/").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")

                .and().exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/errors/403")
                .authenticationEntryPoint(loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint())

                .and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/form?logout")
                .permitAll()

                .and().anonymous()

                .and().csrf().disable()

                // Add custom DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
                .addFilterAt(domainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter domainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter()
            throws Exception {
        DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter dupaf = new DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(
                super.authenticationManagerBean());
        dupaf.setFilterProcessesUrl("/oauth/token");
        dupaf.setUsernameParameter("username");
        dupaf.setPasswordParameter("password");

        dupaf.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(
                new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler(){{
                    setDefaultTargetUrl("/my");
                }}
        );

        dupaf.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(
                new SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler(){{
                    setDefaultFailureUrl("/login/form?error");
                }}
        );

        dupaf.afterPropertiesSet();

        return dupaf;
    }

    @Bean
    public LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint loginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(){
        return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login/form");
    }
}
```

The custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

```
public final class DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    @Autowired
    public DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager){
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String username = obtainUsername(request);
        String password = obtainPassword(request);
        String domain = request.getParameter("domain");

        DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,
                password, domain);

        setDetails(request, authRequest);
        return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
    }

    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

The custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken

```
public final class DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken {
    private final String domain;

    public DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(String principal, String credentials, String domain) {
        super(principal, credentials);
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public DomainUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(Admin principal, String credentials, String domain,
                                                     Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(principal, credentials, authorities);
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5138870746127783L;
}
```